# X-Ray computed tomography

Tags: linear-algebra

Due to certain pandemic,you are tasked with diagnosing lung disases in patients using X-ray computed tomography (in short:X-ray ct).The resulting three-deminsional image of the X-ray absoption coefficients will allow your medical partners to do diagnosis.

You represent the lung are of the patient using a set $v\subset R^3$ hence the lung absorption coefficients can be represent as a continious function $f:v\rightarrow R$. for your computer algorithms,this function $f$ has to be discretized somehow into a discrete $\varsigma$. As an additional difficulty,your X-ray ct scanner has known **non-uniform** scanning characteristics resulting in higher resolution in specific image areas,while the other images areas have lower resolution.

Formulate a suitable mayhematicial representation of the discrete $\varsigma$ based on your knowledge from the BMT course.

I couldn't think of how to formulate it.

Comment: Please provide the source of the problem.

Comment: You must know that you have to integrate function $f$ along rays hopefully multiplied by a function representing the non uniform characteristics. Then in a second step, you discretized all that.

Comment: No comment ?....

Comment: what does BMT course mean?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an octree with different depths for the areas of lower or higher resolution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).